# How can I set my controller and views when I have two Many-to-Many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, blogs, categories

My aim is to organize uploaded posts by categories. These categories are shown on the nav bar and if you click one of the category's names, you will see the posts assigned with the category. When uploading a post, you can assign it with multiple categories too. So, I think this is like many posts can have many categories and many categories can have many posts.

[This is how I want my posts organized by categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzlPq.png)

However, I cannot set things right in my posts_controller.rb, posts/index.html.erb, posts/show.html.erb, and _navigation.html.erb

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  #This validates presence of title, and makes sure that the length is not more than 140 words
  validates :title, presence: true, length: {maximum: 140}
  #This validates presence of body
  validates :body, presence: true
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations 
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :posts, :through => :categorizations
end
```

categorization.rb

```
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :category
end
```

Then, here are these controller and views I am confused with:

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :delete]
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, except: [:index, :show]
  # Index action to render all posts
  def index
    if params.has_key?(:category)
    @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
    @posts = Post.where(category: @category)
    else
    @posts = Post.all
    end
  end

  # New action for creating post
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # Create action saves the post into database
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error creating new post!"
      render :new
    end
  end

  # Edit action retrives the post and renders the edit page
  def edit
  end

  # Update action updates the post with the new information
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated post!"
      redirect_to posts_path(@posts)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error updating post!"
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # The show action renders the individual post after retrieving the the id
  def show 
  end


  # The destroy action removes the post permanently from the database
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.present?
       @post.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted post!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error updating post!"
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, category_ids: [])
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
        <h6><%= post.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %></h6>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= raw post.body.truncate(358) %>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <%= link_to "READ MORE", post_path(post) %>
      </div>
      <% if admin_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to "Show", post_path(post), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), class: "btn btn-default" %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(post), class: "btn btn-danger", data: {:confirm => "Are you sure?"}, method: :delete %>
      <% end %>
      <hr />
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-12 blog-content">
  <h2 class="text-center"><%= @post.title %></h2>
  <h1 class="text-center"><%= @category.name %></h1>
  <h5 class="text-center"><%= @post.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %></h5>
  <div class="text-center"><%= raw @post.body %></div>
</div>
```

_navigation.html.erb(part of it)

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <% Category.all.each do |cat|  %>
    <li class="text-center"><%= link_to cat.name, posts_path(category: cat.name) %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
```

Just in case, schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_11_07_082317) do

  create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "avatar"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admins_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "categories_posts", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.integer "post_id"
  end

  create_table "categorizations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "ckeditor_assets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "data_file_name", null: false
    t.string "data_content_type"
    t.integer "data_file_size"
    t.string "type", limit: 30
    t.integer "width"
    t.integer "height"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["type"], name: "index_ckeditor_assets_on_type"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: What are particular problems with index, show views and navbar? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for fixing my show views. That's what I wanted. Also, I want to achieve sorting posts by categories. So, if you click the category names on the nav bar, you will see all the posts that are within the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In show view you have

```
<h1 class="text-center"><%= @category.name %></h1>
```

But you don't define `@category` in show action. If you want to list categories, it should be

```
<h1 class="text-center"><%= @post.categories.pluck(:name).join(', ') %></h1>
```

Btw, looks like you have useless table `categories_posts` in the schema.rb

Update:

About index action - you should change query for `@posts`, since the post doesn't have a category column, but he has `categories` association:

```
def index
  if params.has_key?(:category)
    # you can remove @category defining if you don't need it somewhere in view
    @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
    @posts = Post.joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: params[:category] } )
  else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Note, it is better to use id for the query, not name, searching by id is faster. You need to change link in navbar to `link_to cat.name, posts_path(category: cat.id)` for it and replace `name` with `id` in the query. And it is better to move the whole query to named scope in the Post model.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to show categories on my post now.

Comment: So, I still want to organize posts in a way I can access certain category posts by clicking category names on the nav bar. Do you have any idea where things are wrong because I get this error when I click on the categories on the nav bar.

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Posts#index
Showing /home/ec2-user/environment/AIU-Blog/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #3 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.category: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."category" = ?
Extracted source (around line #3):
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h2><%= post.title %></h2>

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is solved. So, last question. Won't dropping the categories_posts table affect anything? I guess I have the categorization table so is that okay?

Comment: @KoutaNakano, happy to help you :) It should be OK if you drop the table. I think previously you had `have_and_belongs_to_many` association between posts and categories? Since you changed it to `has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations` you don't need old table anymore

Comment: yes that's right. I was watching this tutorial where I can try both. Thank you very much, have a nice day.